# docker hello world and apache 2

Tags: docker

I am studying docker, and I think I did have installed docker.
But, I cannot run the docker hello-world properly. 
please, see what I want to mean in the screenshot.

[image: here, you can see that the command "docker version" works, but the "docker hello-world" don't]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please post what is shown in the image as text.

Comment: Did you build an image? Can you try running `docker pull hello-world` and share the output so we can see the image SHA?

Comment: Do a `docker rmi hello-world && docker run hello-world`. That should fix the issue

Comment: When I used the pull, it works. Thanks you all

Answer (score 0):

As @tarun said, you should try removing the older `hello-world` image using `docker rmi hello-world` and then restart the container from a new image using `docker run hello-world`